# python spawning enemies on 2 specific locations but randomly

Tags: python, class, pygame

Hi I wanted to make a sprite for a planet, that either spawns at the top of the screen, like halfway on the screen so you only get half the planet, or on the bottom. but I want it to randomly choose to be on the top of the screen or on the bottom. I can't figure it out. my screen is width 1000 and height 500.

```
class Planets(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image_original = random.choice(planet_images)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image_original, (400, 400))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.radius = int(self.rect.width * .95 / 2)
        # Make the hitbox visible --->
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, RED, self.rect.center, self.radius)
        self.rect.x = (1000)
        self.rect.y = -200
        self.speedy = 0
        self.speedx = -2

    def update(self):
        # killing and spawning new enemies when they go of the screen
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.left < - 1400:
            self.kill()
            new_planets = Planets()
            all_sprites.add(new_planets)
            planets.add(new_planets)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `random.choice` again like you did for the images before.
This time you build a list of desired positions on the screen (as tuple with x and y coord) and let random choose where to spawn

```
lst_of_coord = [(1000, -200), (500, 500)] # each tuple for a x,y position on your screen
self.rect.x, self.rect.y = random.choice(lst_of_coord)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thankyou very very much. the solution worked. It now spawns randomly on one of the 2 locations

```
class Planets(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image_original = random.choice(planet_images)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image_original, (400, 400))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.radius = int(self.rect.width * .95 / 2)
        # Make the hitbox visible --->
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, RED, self.rect.center, self.radius)
        list_of_cords = [(1000, -200), (1000, 400)]
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = random.choice(list_of_cords)
        self.speedy = 0
        self.speedx = -2

    def update(self):
        # killing and spawning new enemies when they go of the screen
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.left < - 1400:
            self.kill()
            new_planets = Planets()
            all_sprites.add(new_planets)
            planets.add(new_planets)
```